# Mongoid: inconsistent results on Query when using $elemMatch for nested arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid7

##### Context

```rb
puts [
  "#{RUBY_ENGINE} #{RUBY_VERSION}",
  "Rails gem: #{Rails.gem_version.version}",
  "MongoDB #{Mongoid.default_client.command(buildInfo: 1).first[:version]}",
  "Mongoid gem: #{Mongoid::VERSION}"
].join("\n")
```

```
ruby 2.7.6
Rails gem: 5.2.4.5
MongoDB 4.4.18
Mongoid gem: 7.5.1
```

##### Scenario

To this relationships: `Foo#bars`, `Bar#bazes`, these are the cases aimed for:

1. Identify `Bar` documents where any `label` of bazes matches `cheese`.
2. Identify `Bar` documents where any `id` of bazes matches a target id.
3. Identify `Bar` documents where bazes have any of an array of `id`s.

Although I could work out (1), cases (2) and (3) remain a mystery. Below an example, where in *Queries and Results* there is some example.

##### Example

###### Data Model

```rb
class Baz
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :bar
  field :label, type: String
end
  
class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :foo
  embeds_many :bazes, class_name: "Baz"
end

class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :bars, class_name: "Bar"
end
```

###### Data Sample

```rb
foo = Foo.create!({
  name: "foo",
  bars: [
    {bazes: [{label: "table"}, {label: "chair"}]},
    {bazes: [{label: "bread"}, {label: "cheese"}]},
    {bazes: [{label: "up"}, {label: "down"}]},
    {bazes: [{label: "high"}]},
    {bazes: [{label: "low"}]}
  ]
})
```

##### Queries and Results

Select the target for cases (1) and (2):

```rb
baz = foo.bars[1].bazes.last
baz.label
#=> "cheese"
baz.id
#=> BSON::ObjectId('638d3b824b9f26049b42ac0a')
```

**Case 1**

```rb
foo.bars.where(bazes: {"$elemMatch": {label: baz.label}}).count
#=> 1
```

It seems to be working properly. Doing some double check:

```rb
bazes = foo.bars.where(bazes: {"$elemMatch": {label: baz.label}}).pluck(:bazes).first
found = bazes.where(label: baz.label).first
#=> #<Baz _id: 638d3b824b9f26049b42ac0a, label: "cheese">
found == baz
#=> true
```

It certainly worked.

**Case 2**

Using exactly the same syntax as in Case (1), but matching the `id` field instead:

```rb
foo.bars.where(bazes: {"$elemMatch": {id: baz.id}}).count
#=> 0
```

It does **not** work.

At this point I am quite lost. How would a field like `label` work but the `id` wouldn't?

**Case 3**

The below is what I guess it should look like. It doesn't work either, although it makes sense, given that the base case (2) above fails in the first place...

```rb
foo.bars.where(bazes: {"$elemMatch": {:id.in => [baz.id]}}).count
#=> 0
```

Comment: I haven't used Ruby in a long time (before Rails!). I have fond memories of it, but little detail remains in my mini cranial FIFO. I do have some active MongoDB knowledge. Looking at your schema, etc., I doubt `id` is a field of any element in `bazes`.  `id` here is probably the `"_id"` field present in every MongoDB document.  When querying, unless specifically repressed or reassigned due to, e.g. a `"$group"`, `"_id"` is projected and returned with the doc.  I guess that's what `baz.id` is here.  So, if you query the `bazes` array elements for `id`, it won't be found because it's not there.

Comment: @rickhg12hs you are right... I must be blind. Tried also in the real case with `_id:` but must have left it behind at some stage. Thank you!